# What distinguishes CCITT .tif files from jpeg compression .tif

Tags: c#

I've written a code to detect corruption of jpeg files by comparing the last two bytes if they have the jpeg marker

```
if (buffer[0] == (byte)0xff && buffer[1] == (byte)0xd9)
{
    validJpeg = true;
}
```

The code works fine with .tif files using jpeg compression but if the images are using CCITT (Group 4 in my case) compression , all those images are wrongly recognized as corrupted .

How can i add to the if clause , the corresponding part (marker) for CCITT compression images?

Thanks everyone !

Comment: Are you sure such a value exists as TIFF does not use markers in that way.  The file format has a main header (8 bytes) then pairs of header & image data where each header provides the address of the next image header.

Comment: _"I've written a code to detect corruption of jpeg files"_ - why? Can you define "a corrupt jpeg file"? Why do you think only those two bytes can get corrupted? Can't you better make sure they don't get corrupted in the first place, for example by fixing the defect that causes them to be corrupted in the first place? Are you confusing corruption and compression?

Comment: trailing `FF` `D9` are not an indication of a valid JPEG file at all. TIFF files with JPEG compression have even more complex structure and again the mentioned markers don't let you tell the validity. Basically you just need to refer to JPEG and TIFF specifications.

Answer (score 0):

0xffd9 doesn't appear to be a legal compression tag, so I'm not sure what you're testing against.  Are you parsing tags, or just jumping into the image data?  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) says G4 is indicated by the compression tag (0x0103) having the value 0x0004.

If you really need to identify if a sequence of bytes could represent G4-compressed data, you should consult the [specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.6-198811-I/en).  Is seems that the data will end with the 3 hex bytes 0x00 0x10 0x01.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I've been searching for a way to detect truncated jpeg files, and i found this program in java web.archive.org/web/20081219033217/http://schmidt.devlib.org/… which works great as it detects corrupt(truncated) images,and null images that can't open . Basically the program checks if the image has more than 50 bytes and if it does it checks the last two bytes (EOF) to see if the image ended successfully .Those with CCITT compression don't have a standard EOF ,it is always different therefore this IF check won't work for them